# How could i update a table each time a materialized view is refreshed?

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

So i have a table which contains the last modification or refresh date for every MV in our db. I would like to update this value each time a MV refreshes. I thought the following could be possible, but i dont know how to accomplish it :

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ...
 .
 .
 ** UPDATE TABLE AFTER REFRESH **
 .
 .
 AS
 SELECT ......
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the dictionary

```
select mview_name , last_refresh_type,last_refresh_date from all_mviews;
```

Comment: So this means i have to execute a procedure that will update the last MV refreshed? I cant update from the MV creation header?

Comment: You said you want to know the last refresh time of each mview in the database. oracle maintains a dictionary table called `all_mviews` that updates every time a mview is refreshed. instead of creating your own table you can use this one.

Comment: Interesting, but since i didnt design the db i still have to update that table. Keeping that in mind, which do you think is the best way to accomplish this? Thx for your help

Comment: you are confused. read [here](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-fmt.html) about oracle dictionary. you don't have to maintain anything. this is the beauty. descriptive data can always be retrieved from the dictionary.